# Gridgain serialization exception

Tags: gridgain

I am trying out gridgain for the first time and facing some issues with serialization. While trying to use GridClosure to project jobs on different nodes I get marshaling exception . On debugging, It seems the failure is always for Apache log4j Logger object. Its difficult for me to avoid loggers and wanted to understand if this is a known issue or someway I can remedy this. I have requireSerializable set to false for my grid config.

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.writeSerializable(GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:292)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.writeSerializable(GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:295)
    at org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedClassDescriptor.write(GridOptimizedClassDescriptor.java:849)
    at org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:198)
    at org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:129)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:342)
    at java.util.Hashtable.writeObject(Hashtable.java:988)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.writeSerializable(GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:292)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.value(GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:1003)
    at org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.put(GridOptimizedObjectOutputStream.java:965)
    at java.util.Vector.writeObject(Vector.java:1068)
    ... 60 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you make Log4J object static so it does not affect serialization? If not, GridGain allows you to inject logger resource into pretty much anything, including closures. You can configure GridLogger as GridLog4jLogger in GridConfiguration.

Here is an example:

```
GridRunnable run = new GridRunnable() {
    // Can be any logger, including GridLog4jLogger.
    @GridLoggerResource
    GridLogger log;

    @Override public void run() {
        log.info("Hello");

        // Do some logic.
    }
}
```

or

```
// Can be any logger, including GridLog4jLogger
final GridLogger log = grid.log();

GridRunnable run = new GridRunnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        log.info("Hello");

        // Do some logic.
    }
}
```

For more information, refer to [Resource Injection](http://atlassian.gridgain.com/wiki/display/GG60/Resource+Injection) page in GridGain documentation.

Comment: Thanks Dmitriy. I am trying to enhance current project with grid gain distribution. Most of the classes in current project have static loggers but there are some non-static (legacy) loggers. When I try to invoke routines in those classes from within Grid ClosureI get these exceptions. I might not have the liberty to change all of them.

Comment: @GDS Generally GridGain is OK serializing non-serializable classes, but in case of log4j it requires some initialization. You may also look into declaring loggers as transient fields and lazily initializing them on remote nodes. Perhaps, if you post your code, I could be more of a help.

Comment: its difficult to post entire code and I am not able to reproduce on a smaller example. However, I did manage to have a work around and use only static loggers and its working fantastic.Thanks.